# ListView does not respond to pressing in SlidingMenu

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I develop a simple application, and faced with such a problem. 
ListView does not respond to clicks in SlidingMenu

As created SlidingMenu

```
private SlidingMenu menu;
---
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadows_menu_swype1);
menu.setShadowWidth(15);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.50f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setBehindWidth(300);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_swype);
```

How to create a ListView

```
SwypeMenuLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_swypeID); 
String[] menu_swypeStr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_swypeSTR); 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_menu_swype, menu_swypeStr); 
SwypeMenuLV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ListView event handlers

```
SwypeMenuLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                    
       toast.setText("TEST!");
   toast.show();                        
     }
});
```

XML ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shadows_menu_swype2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/menu_swypeID"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/boder_menu_swype"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp">
 </ListView>
```

list_item_menu_swype.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#f4f5f5"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    >
</TextView>
```

What is wrong?
Please, help!)

Comment: Please show list_item_menu_swype code

Comment: certainly added a bit higher in the post